# NGINX always returns GET in PHP $_SERVER array, even when it's not

Tags: nginx

I'm struggling with an NGINX config issue on my LEMP stack. In PHP, the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` always has a value of GET, even when the request method is POST.

Running:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- PHP Version 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.6
- nginx/1.14.0

Here's the server config:

```
server {
    server_name    my-site.com;
    root           /var/www/my-site.com/html/;
    index          index.php index.html;

  location ~* \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    include         fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
  }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /api/index.php?$query_string;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-site.com-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-site.com-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = my-site.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name    my-site.com;

    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

I've read around a bit on this, and checked to make sure that `/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params` is the Ubuntu/NGINX default:

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

Anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: I don't see an issue there. Please post the output from `nginx -T`.

Comment: Check the access log. Is there a 301 redirection? That will change a POST to a GET.

Comment: @RichardSmith - YES this was it. HTTP to HTTPS redirect by certbot caused this. I am going to just close port 80 on this server

Answer (score 1):

Turns our as per @richardsmith in the comments above, the HTTPS to HTTP redirect was causing the method to change from POST to GET.